# Get number of days between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, time

|  | Fleet_ID | State | ODO_Reading | Date_Added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F1 | State 1 | 42000 | 10/01/2021 |
| 2 | F1 | State 1 | 43100 | 14/03/2021 |
| 3 | F1 | State 1 | 43900 | 26/04/2021 |
| 4 | F2 | State 1 | 63010 | 22/02/2021 |
| 5 | F2 | State 1 | 70800 | 06/04/2021 |
| 6 | F3 | State 2 | 17000 | 03/01/2021 |
| 7 | F3 | State 2 | 18560 | 19/03/2021 |
| 8 | F3 | State 2 | 19695 | 23/04/2021 |

Above is a sample database

Is it just a simple GET DATE command in order to get the number of days between two dates?
I have tried to GET DATE but I must be doing it incorrectly.

I basically want to know the time passed in days between the dates in rows 1 & 2.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `datediff` and `lead` like this

```
datediff(Date_added,lead(Date_added,1))
```